# IBAction NSString error

Tags: ios

Here is my sample code:

```
IBaction*NSstring = error
```

help PLS! cause this sheeit is annoying

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: Try using Storyboards/Interface builder to make your IBAction. The correct code will be generated for you. Also, an IBaction cannot be a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because an `NSString` object can't be of `IBOutlet` - `IBOutlet` has to be of Interface Builder (view objects/subclasses)